# How can i turn on Virtualization?

Tags: virtual-machine, hardware-virtualization

I have Dell  760 which bios doesn't show any virtualization options but see the older versions have an option to turn on virtualization but when i go to the bios it doesn't have what should i do upgrade my bios?

Comment: e7300 is the processor number

Comment: I don't know what the heck to install ? when i turn on my Virtual Box  it says Vt- x is not enabled

Comment: Your [processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/36463/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7300-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) does not feature VT-x.

Comment: Indeed thats the problem

Comment: Updating your BIOS will not solve the problem. You will need to upgrade your CPU.

Comment: If Virtualization doesn't work is partitioning my disk into 2 pieces then downloading the other operating system is this a good idea or not?

Comment: Sure, there's nothing wrong with going with a dual boot setup instead.

Comment: Windows XP is terrible even in my dreams i shall not use that crappy OS anymore

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided your computer hardware does not support virtualization.

At minimum you must have a different processor (CPU) that supports virtualization.